# Using a custom reverse manager in Filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-managers

Given I have:

```
class Publisher(Model):
  pass

class Author(Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
  is_alive = models.BooleanField(...)
  objects = models.Manager()  # Default Manager
  alives = AliveManager()    # Custom Manager
```

Right now I can filter using:

```
Publisher.objects.filter(author__name='xxx', author__is_alive=True)
```

My question is there anyway to take advantage of a [custom reverse manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) in the filter statement?

```
publisher.author_set(manager="alives")
```

gives me this for a given publisher.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. A manager is a manager, not a filter condition. How would you want to use a manager in the filter?

Comment: Given that I have written a Manager that filters the Authors I want, is there any way to use that Manager when writing a filter on the Publisher queryset? I would like to find all Publishers have have authors that are alive and the author's name is in XXX.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is the relevant bit in the docs:

> [...] default filtering in its get_queryset() method, that filtering would apply to the all() call.

```
class AliveManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(AliveManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(is_alive=True)

class Author(Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    is_alive = models.BooleanField(...)
    objects = models.Manager()  # Default Manager
    alives = AliveManager()    # Custom Manager


# returns all alive authors
publisher.author_set(manager='alives').all()
# filters through alive authors
publisher.author_set(manager='alives').filter(author__name='xxx')
```

Comment: I would like to end up with a Publisher queryset.

Comment: If you want to get publishers with alive authors, add a manager for the Publisher model instead. You can't use the other model manager as far a I know.

Comment: @AlexRothberg, can you please want to share your end solution here.